# Sort and Slice DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a dataframe like given below:

```
    detaildate  detailquantity
0   2012-02-09  7.0
1   2011-05-27  -1.0
2   2011-05-04  -2.0
3   2012-03-19  -2.0
4   2012-03-18  -3.0
```

I want to first sort the above dataframe by `detaildate` and then slice the dataframe from the first positive value of `detailquantity` to last index.

The result dataframe should look like this:

```
    detaildate  detailquantity
0   2012-02-09  7.0
4   2012-03-18  -3.0
3   2012-03-19  -2.0
```

I am trying the below code but it is resulting in an empty dataframe at the end and I am not able to figure out why

```
df.sort_values(by='detaildate', inplace=True)
df = df[df[df['detailquantity'] > 0].first_valid_index():]
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Do you mind to reformulate the logic that lead to the output?

Comment: what is the last index definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with boolean mask and test all values greater like `0`, solution also working correctly if all negative values:

```
df.sort_values(by='detaildate', inplace=True)

df = df[(df['detailquantity'] > 0).cumsum() > 0]
print (df)
   detaildate  detailquantity
0  2012-02-09             7.0
4  2012-03-18            -3.0
3  2012-03-19            -2.0
```

Your solution should be changed by creating unique index, but is necessary at least one value matched:

```
df.sort_values(by='detaildate', inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.loc[(df['detailquantity'] > 0).idxmax():]
print (df)
   detaildate  detailquantity
2  2012-02-09             7.0
3  2012-03-18            -3.0
4  2012-03-19            -2.0
```

Another alternative in numpy:

```
df.sort_values(by='detaildate', inplace=True)

df = df.iloc[(df['detailquantity'].values > 0).argmax():]
print (df)
   detaildate  detailquantity
0  2012-02-09             7.0
4  2012-03-18            -3.0
3  2012-03-19            -2.0
```